# Hazelcast semaphore via its REST API

Tags: hazelcast

I was wondering if it is possible (and if so how) to acquire/release an Hazelcast semaphore, more specifically a mutex, **using REST**. I found some documentation on how to use maps, queues, amongst other Hazelcast features with REST (e.g. [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Hazelcast_Clients/REST_Client.html)), but I failed to find it for concurrency features like semaphores.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, REST client is pretty minimal and it doesn't have support for ISemaphore. See [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/ascii/rest/HttpCommandProcessor.java) to see it's capabilities.

If REST is the only way, you can [contribute](https://hazelcast.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/COM/pages/27558010/Hazelcast+Enhancement+Proposals) the code for an ISemaphore endpoint, or use a Java Client and expose it through a REST API on your side.